# Receive notification event from webhook in test script which uses mocha

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mocha.js, integration-testing

We are writing integration test in which we want to receive event from webhook. Is there any way it can be done ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i started web server using http to listen events and stopping the server once testcases are executed.